# How to find Xcode file?

Tags: swift, xcode

Inside of my Xcode project I have an *awsconfiguration.json* file. However whenever I build the project xcode says **error: /Users/hunter/Desktop/project5/awsconfiguration.json: No such file or directory (in target 'project5' from project 'project5')**. This error began to show after I pushed the project to GitHub and tried to run it on a different computer. The file shows up in the project navigator but is greyed out. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Please check if awsconfiguration.json exists in your local project
2. Please check if * .json was added to your git ignore file?
3. Please check your GitHub for awsconfiguration.json file

Comment: It is in my git ignore file. Is that the problem?

Comment: @AKH It means that files included in git ignore files are not uploaded to your git server, you can delete * .json and upload it to github again

Comment: Im fairly new to git. Can I just remove the `awsconfiguration.json` line from the gitignore file and push the project again?

Comment: Yes,if you want to clone the project elsewhere and still use it, of course you should remove it in git ignore file

Comment: `git clone git@github.com:yourname/yourgit.git`   [git-guide](https://www.bootcss.com/p/git-guide/), (If the answer helps you, please vote for more people to see)

Comment: I removed it from the file however when I clone it, its still missing.

Comment: @AKH Did you re-upload after deleting?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209345/discussion-between-akh-and-ink).